# Show human error if inserting duplicate data in access database

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I've prohibited duplicate records in access database so no one will insert same data again and again. it works fine, but the error message is not helpful to the users, i want to show that error in a more human way possible.

> Microsoft JET Database Engine (**0x80004005**)
>
> The changes you requested to the table were not successful because
>   they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or
>   relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain
>   duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit
>   duplicate entries and try again.

Instead of this lengthy message i just want to show "Sorry - Record already exist."

Is this possible?

Comment: you could check if the data exist in the DB before you do the insert and show a message if it does ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

1. Catch the error.  I think classic ASP requires `on error resume next` and then you need to check the err message.  You might even have to match the string since I think the error code will be the same for different errors.
2. Do a `select` from the database before the `insert` to check if the value already exists

Either way you can then display your own message.  Might be even more user-friendly to customize the message further ("Sorry - species 'Gruffalo' already exists").

Comment: I followed your 2nd logic and it worked now :) thanks Colin. here is what i did `If uid > 0 Then
Response.Write("Sorry - Record Already Exist!!!")
Else insert into DB`